# Centrino Wireless-N 1000 BGN | Getting internet speed 13.5 Mb/s (connected to 270 Mb/s)

Tags: wireless, network-manager, iwlwifi, network-monitoring, download-speed

**Problem**
Internet speed (wireless connection) on my PC is extremely poor whereas other devices (like cell phone, ipad etc.) using the same network works fine.

**Solutions tried so far but no luck**

1. disable power management
2. remove backport-iwlwifi-dkms (actually not installed)

Refer attached complete details based on Wireless Info script [wirelessinfo.txt](https://pastebin.com/Vsf82jsU)

[dmesg](https://pastebin.com/kMkLYbSr) and [journalctl](https://pastebin.com/jU86cepi) is also attached for ready reference.

Would appreciate if somebody can help.

Comment: Don't look at the speed displayed by iwconfig. What speed do you get on a [speed test](https://beta.speedtest.net). Mine shows 6.5Mb/s, yet pulls 300Mb/s without problem... It should also be noted that your [card is from 2011](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/59480/intel-centrino-wireless-n-1000-single-band.html), and wifi performance has made huge leaps in those ten years.

Comment: @vidarlo i mentioned the figures just to help assess gravity of the situation. However whenever network speed drops, i am not even unable to load home page of speedtest.net

Comment: Does your other devices by any chance support 802.11ac, and does your access point support this? Is it possible that they're using the 5GHz band?

Comment: @vidarlo I don't think so. For instance, my cell phone (Motorola G3) is using 2.4 GHz Link speed 72 Mbps and I am not facing any such issues with it

Comment: See if itis better after `sudo iwconfig  wlp3s0 power off`

Comment: @Jeremy31 already tried but didn't found any noticeable improvement

Comment: Also try `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sleep 5 && sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=8` that should see if aggressive TX helps

Comment: @Jeremy31 Will try this. Thanks, let me get back after 24 hours.

Comment: @Jeremy31 i had to try a little modified version `sudo modprobe -rfv iwldvm && sleep 5 && sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi 11n_disable=8` which is giving (if not the best but still a) better result. Will now experiment with `11n_disable=1` & see if I could get any further improvements